# Is it possible to integrate AJAX toolkit into MVC applications?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, toolkit

How do I integrate AJAX toolkit into MVC applications in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure particularly which toolkit you are referring to but have a look this by Stephen Walther.  Here he uses Ajax Control toolkit with asp.net MVC to create an AutoComplete Text field.

[ASP.NET MVC Tip #37](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/08/23/asp-net-mvc-tip-37-create-an-auto-complete-text-field.aspx)

Comment: This link is (currently) a better one - and will show ALL MVC blogs from Stephen. i dont like the blogging system he's using because there isnt even a 'next page' option so this shows everything. http://stephenwalther.com/blog/category/4.aspx?Show=All

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, AJAX Control Toolkit should be included in the Beta!